# Background Fetch and UILocalNotifications

Tags: ios, iphone, uilocalnotification

Is it valid to schedule a `UILocalNotification`, to alert the user to new content during an iOS 7 background fetch, if new content is available?

Ie. are there restrictions with communicating with the user, should the background fetch be transparent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily schedule any local notification in

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

before the line

```
completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
```

to notify user at the moment or any further time.

Comment: Great thanks, I was under the impression that the system would be responsible for updating the multitasking UI to show new content had arrived, and potentially it was breaking the HIG to pop your own notification to alert the user to new content, but if not great!

Comment: Why could it break HIG? I think that there is no strong difference between notification on arrival of new content which is important for user and notification about forthcoming calendar meeting.